# Can the -replace option replace multiple lines?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm attempting to create shortcuts to launch particular games through DOSBox for my son, and I'm attempting this by dynamically changing the "[autoexec]" portion of the DOSBox ".conf" file with this script:

```
((Get-Content -path C:\Users\skewb\AppData\Local\DOSBox\dosbox-0.74-3.conf -Raw) -replace "\[autoexec\]*", "`[autoexec`]`nMOUNT C`r`nE:\Games\DOSGames`r`nC:`r`ncd SSGG`r`nssg`r`n") | Set-Content -Path C:\Users\skewb\AppData\Local\DOSBox\dosbox-0.74-3.conf
start-process "D:\Program Files (x86)\DOSBox-0.74-3\DOSBox.exe"
```

I've almost gotten it to work but now every time I run the script, it's appending to the end of the autoexec portion (well... technically the beginning of the portion but w/e) like this:

Original:

```
[autoexec]
# Lines in this section will be run at startup.
# You can put your MOUNT lines here.
```

Expected output:

```
[autoexec]
MOUNT C
E:\Games\DOSGames
C:
cd SSGG
ssg
```

Actual Output:

```
[autoexec]
MOUNT C
E:\Games\DOSGames
C:
cd SSGG
ssg

MOUNT C
E:\Games\DOSGames
C:
cd SSGG
ssg

MOUNT C
E:\Games\DOSGames
C:
cd SSGG
ssg

MOUNT C
E:\Games\DOSGames
C:
cd SSGG
ssg

MOUNT C
E:\Games\DOSGames
C:
cd SSGG
ssg
# Lines in this section will be run at startup.
# You can put your MOUNT lines here.
```

It appears to identify the `[autoexec]` portion correctly, but then stops at the newline I guess?
I've also tried identifying the newlines in the "find" like this (to no avail of course):

```
((Get-Content -path C:\Users\skewb\AppData\Local\DOSBox\dosbox-0.74-3.conf -Raw) -replace "\[autoexec\](`r`n)(*)", "`[autoexec`]`nMOUNT C`r`nE:\Games\DOSGames`r`nC:`r`ncd SSGG`r`nssg`r`n") | Set-Content -Path C:\Users\skewb\AppData\Local\DOSBox\dosbox-0.74-3.conf
```

Comment: Rather than trying to modify the DOSBox config file, why not leave it the same, calling a batch file at the end, and just replacing the contents of the batch file being called?

Comment: Are you sure you do not just simple need to use ``"`[autoexec`]`r`nMOUNT C`r`nE:\Games\DOSGames`r`nC:`r`ncd SSGG`r`nssg`r`n")`` instead? Is it expected to have Linux `LF` after `[autoexec]` then Windows `CRLF` after each subsequent new line? When I run the process with your sample data, I get the expected output but see that LF and CRLF mix as the only thing I see that could throw something off perhaps. Let me know.